# AWS: Do the AWS IAM role and IAM user permissions add up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

let's say I have an EC2 instance with a java application that is using the AWS SDK and some IAM User credentials. IAM User has permission to invoke only lambda function A, and I attached IAM Role to this EC2 instance with permissions to invoke lambda function B.

Will the java application have permission to invoke B lambda because of the IAM Role?

Comment: Generally, don't use IAM user credentials with EC2. Use an IAM role instead. In your case, you have two sets of credentials. The permissions you have depend on which you present to the SDK for a given API call (the implicit IAM role credentials or the explicit IAM user credentials).

Answer (score 0):

> Will the java application have permission to invoke B lambda because of the IAM Role?

Yes, because your AWS Java SDK will use the instance role. IAM user permissions are irrelevant in that case, unless you specially program your application to use IAM user permissions, not the instance role.

Comment: that's the case, the java application explicitly uses the IAM User credentials to invoke lambdas

Comment: @pumba So you have to modify your application. Only you know how your application works.